What functions can you use inside tidyverse's summarise? A simple example fails
I have a dataframe samples which has 50 rows, 10 for each of 5 samples. In this df, the sample no is labelled by a column sample_no.
I also have a function f which takes a sample and returns a one-row summary data frame. When I write:
samples %>%
group_by(sample_no) %>%
dplyr::summarise( d = f(.) ) %>%
unpack(cols = d)```

f seems to see all samples at once (50 rows) rather than one sample at a time (10 rows). By contrast
f(samples %>% filter(sample_no == 1))

Sees 10 rows as I would expect.
Is it the case that only certain special functions can be used inside summarise, and that those functions have to be 'group-aware'? Or is something else happening?
MWE:
library(tidyverse)

SAMPLE_SIZE <- 10
NSAMPLES <- 5

fresh_sample <- function() {
  data.frame(F = rnorm(SAMPLE_SIZE, 0, 1))
}

# I'd also love to know if there is a neater way to do this...
samples <- do.call(rbind, lapply(1:NSAMPLES, function(k) {
  fresh_sample() %>% mutate(sample_no = k)
}))

# I don't actually need to compute dimensions. 
# The actual computation I want to apply to a sample is much more complex.
dims <- function(sample) {
  data.frame(nrow = nrow(sample), ncol = ncol(sample))
}

# This returns a 1-row df, with      nrow = 10, ncol = 2
dims(samples %>% filter(sample_no == 1))

# This returns a 5-row df, each with nrow = 50, ncol = 2
samples %>%
  group_by(sample_no) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(d = dims(.)) %>%
  unpack(cols = d)


"Is it the case that only certain special functions can be used inside summarise, and that those functions have to be 'group-aware'?" No, that is not the case.

As for "a neater way to do this", I'd suggest samples <- replicate(n = NSAMPLES, fresh_sample(), simplify = FALSE) |>   bind_rows(.id = "sample_no")

If you only want to see samples one at a time, you could split them up, iterate through each one applying the function, then optionally rebind the results, e.g. samples |> group_split(sample_no) |> map(dims) |> bind_rows()

@GregorThomas Unfortunately that gives me sample_no as a string rather than an int. Is there an easy workaround? (Other than reparsing the string as an int.)

No workaround easier than as.integer(). But since you're (presumably) not doing math with an ID number, it shouldn't matter either class.

Add some verbosity to dims() to see what it gets called with:
dims <- function(sample) {
  message(str(sample))
  data.frame(nrow = nrow(sample), ncol = ncol(sample))
}

samples %>%
  group_by(sample_no) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(d = dims(.)) %>%
  unpack(cols = d)

And you'll see that the . here is evaluated as a complete grouped data.frame, not just as a subset:
gropd_df [50 × 2] (S3: grouped_df/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ F        : num [1:50] -0.7209 -0.0633 0.5131 -1.0099 2.0664 ...
 $ sample_no: int [1:50] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 - attr(*, "groups")= tibble [5 × 2] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  ..$ sample_no: int [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
  ..$ .rows    : list<int> [1:5] 
  .. ..$ : int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
  .. ..$ : int [1:10] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
  .. ..$ : int [1:10] 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
  .. ..$ : int [1:10] 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40
  .. ..$ : int [1:10] 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50
  .. ..@ ptype: int(0) 
  ..- attr(*, ".drop")= logi TRUE

/ ... /

# A tibble: 5 × 3
  sample_no  nrow  ncol
      <int> <int> <int>
1         1    50     2
2         2    50     2
3         3    50     2
4         4    50     2
5         5    50     2

Let's keep the message(str(sample)) bit to see how dims() argument changes, but call it through group_modify(), which also keeps that grouping var for us:
library(tidyverse)

SAMPLE_SIZE <- 10
NSAMPLES <- 5

fresh_sample <- function() {
  data.frame(F = rnorm(SAMPLE_SIZE, 0, 1))
}

samples <- do.call(rbind, lapply(1:NSAMPLES, function(k) {
  fresh_sample() %>% mutate(sample_no = k)
}))

dims <- function(sample) {
  message(str(sample))
  data.frame(nrow = nrow(sample), ncol = ncol(sample))
}

samples %>%
  group_by(sample_no) %>%
  # data frame in, data frame out, keep grouping key
  group_modify(~ dims(.x)) %>% 
  ungroup()
#> tibble [10 × 1] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#>  $ F: num [1:10] -1.436 -0.741 0.659 1.134 -1.64 ...
#> 
#> tibble [10 × 1] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#>  $ F: num [1:10] 1.093 0.844 -1.249 -1.182 0.784 ...
#> 
#> tibble [10 × 1] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#>  $ F: num [1:10] 1.663 0.992 -0.647 0.473 -1.195 ...
#> 
#> tibble [10 × 1] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#>  $ F: num [1:10] 0.625 -0.622 0.26 -0.471 -0.408 ...
#> 
#> tibble [10 × 1] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#>  $ F: num [1:10] 1.492 0.608 0.751 1.167 -0.421 ...

Resulting frame:
#> # A tibble: 5 × 3
#>   sample_no  nrow  ncol
#>       <int> <int> <int>
#> 1         1    10     1
#> 2         2    10     1
#> 3         3    10     1
#> 4         4    10     1
#> 5         5    10     1

Note that in this case (summary function is returning a data.frame of 1 row) you can still use summarise(), but instead of passing the whole input frame to the function with ... %>% summarise(d = dims(.)), you'd need something to get subsets. This is what you can use pick() for:
# .by instead of group_by() for convenience;
# note how `pick(everything())` excludes grouping var and
# dims() receives 10×1 tibble 
samples %>%
  summarise(d = dims(pick(everything())), .by = sample_no) %>% 
  unpack(d)
#> tibble [10 × 1] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#>  $ F: num [1:10] -2.414 -1.257 -0.752 -0.166 -1.337 ...
#> / ... /
#> 
#> # A tibble: 5 × 3
#>   sample_no  nrow  ncol
#>       <int> <int> <int>
#> 1         1    10     1
#> 2         2    10     1
#> 3         3    10     1
#> 4         4    10     1
#> 5         5    10     1


Illuminating!   How do you tell which functions need group_modify and which don't?  The docs simply say to supply 'Name-value pairs of summary functions.'...

This is kind of opinionated, but in summarise() I personally would stick with (and expect) functions that take a vector & return a scalar,  perhaps also functions that return a frame (different aggregations of a single vector),  but something that takes a frame as input is often more of a lapply / purrr::map()  & co territory, even if it returns just one row, i.e. summarises. group_map() / group_modify() / group_walk()  bring map() & co to grouped tibbles. I added another example with summarise() & pick(), which actually might be closer to the answer you were expecting.

Opinionated is helpful! R seems to have many ways to do things and I am having real trouble figuring out what is good style. Is it normal to mix purrr and dplyr?

When it comes to Tidyverse, R4DS - https://r4ds.hadley.nz/ - and Vignettes (e.g. https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/dplyr.html , https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/index.html ) are quite good resources when you feel you need to build some intuition for where to use what.
